# Accessing an inline function through a const member variable

Tags: c++, constants, inline, member-functions, const-cast

I wanted to understand how the inline member variable work while accessing it through a const member variable.
Each time I try doing so, I get an error!

This is what I am trying

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    A()
    {
        _uuid = 0;
    }
    ~A();
    void setUUID(int n) { _uuid = n; }
    inline int getUUID(){  return _uuid;} const
    int getUUID1() const {  return _uuid;} 
    int getUUIDsmart()const 
    { 
        return _uuid; 
    }
    private:
    int _uuid;    
};

class B {
    public:
    B(){}
    ~B();
    void fun1(const A *obj) 
    {
        cout<<obj->getUUIDsmart()<<endl;   //works fine
        cout<<obj->getUUID1()<<endl;       //works fine
        cout<<obj->getUUID()<<endl;        //error

        A *obj1 = const_cast<A *>(obj);
        cout<<obj1->getUUID()<<endl;       //works fine
    }
};

int main()
{
  B *b = new B;
  A *a = new A;
  a->setUUID(12);
  b->fun1(a);
}
```

I am able to get my code work through

> const_cast

But I am interested in knowing why do i get an error in the inline function if I try accessing it through a const member function?

### Update: FIX

My bad. I had the placement of const messed up!
Thanks to @bruno

```
inline int getUUID() const { return _uuid; }
//correct syntax. i placed the const at the end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[note : I use the first version of the question]

you place wrongly your const :

```
inline int getUUID(){  return _uuid;} const
int getUUID1(){  return _uuid;} const
int getUUIDsmart()const
```

is in fact

```
inline int getUUID(){  return _uuid;} 
const int getUUID1(){  return _uuid;} 
const int getUUIDsmart()const
```

I just moved the *const* on the right line for readability reason

You wanted

```
inline int getUUID() const {  return _uuid;}
int getUUID1() const{  return _uuid;}
```

in your version none of *getUUID1* nor *getUUID* are *const* so you cannot apply them on a *const* instance

There is no link at all with the fact your methods are inline or not.

---

Note :

```
cout<<obj->getUUID1()<<endl;       //works fine
```

it doesn't

Comment: you are correct! But the code with //error interests me more. This is just a instance of my actual code. I'll correct the point observed.

Comment: @skuila did you read my answer ? : _in your version none of getUUID1 nor getUUID are const so you cannot apply them on a const instance_

Comment: it is a link to an online c++ compiler i am using to check the output with code changes quickly
you can access the url too
cpp.sh/47ei62

Comment: @skuila you do not used the same definition, on it you use `int getUUID1() const {  return _uuid;} ` so it is _const_, this is not the case in your question ... before you edit it

Comment: I'm not sure that i was able to express my question clearly. I made a blunder in writing the declaration for getUUID1() but I want to know why getUUID() doesn't work?
I'll edit my question appropriately but (no offense) your answer still doesn't explain the why can't I call an inline function in a const member variable !

Comment: @skuila ? I already said you several times _getUUID_ is **not** _const_, it is `inline int getUUID(){  return _uuid;}` rather than `inline int getUUID() const {  return _uuid;}`, because of that you cannot apply it on a const instance like _obj_ is

Comment: I got your point
its the syntax!
thanks!
:)
sorry for the trouble!